# Smtp mail delivered unsuccessfully

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I am using Smtp to send mail.A message was sent successfully but it was not delivered. What is the reason behind this.Is this a problem in mailing server?The message sending process is working fine for the last couple of years.The issue came first time.

```
public bool SendMail(string p_strFrom, string p_strDisplayName, string p_strTo, string p_strSubject, string p_strMessage , string strFileName)
 {
     try
     {
         p_strDisplayName = _DisplayName;
         string smtpserver = _SmtpServer;
         SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
         MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
         MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(_From,_DisplayName);
         smtpClient.Host = _SmtpServer;
         smtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(_Port);
         string strAuth_UserName = _UserName;
         string strAuth_Password = _Password;
         if (strAuth_UserName != null)
         {
             System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strAuth_UserName, strAuth_Password);
             smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
             if (_SSL)
             {
                 smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
             }
             smtpClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
         }
         message.From = fromAddress;

         message.Subject = p_strSubject;
         message.IsBodyHtml = true;
         message.Body = p_strMessage;
         message.To.Add(p_strTo);
         try
         {
             smtpClient.Send(message);
             Log.WriteSpecialLog("smtpClient mail sending first try success", "");
         }
          catch (Exception ee)
         {
             Log.WriteSpecialLog("smtpClient mail sending first try Failed : " + ee.ToString(), "");
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Log.WriteLog("smtpClient mail sending overall failed : " + ex.ToString());  
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: MailMessage and SmtpClient both implement IDisposable. In particular, disposing SmtpClient is important. It's likely the cause of your problem, but it's a change you should make.

Comment: How can i disposible SmtpClient.I am using .Net 3.5

Comment: IDisposable was added to SmtpClient in .Net 4.0. If you're using 3.5, my comment on disposing it doesn't apply.

Comment: OK.Is there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> A message was sent successfully but it was not delivered

If it was sent successfully from your mailing server then the possible reason of non delivery can be that the mail filter on client blocked it or is delivered in the junk.

Comment: when i re-sent it,delivered successfully